# Conversion of crystal report of Desktop application to web application's crystal report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have got a desktop application which was build in vs2005, now i am doing conversion of it to web application (vs2008). 
i have got around 40 crystal reports in it (desktop application).

please tell me can i use them (rpt files) directly in web application or i will have to create all new reports?

please provide me solution or give me some good URL which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for creating new reports you can use the rpt files in the web application just as it was a desktop one and regardless of the version of VS.

All you need is to install Crystal Redistributable packs on the server that is hosting the application.